# QUnit–chain asynchronous tests

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, qunit, method-chaining

I would like to write tests that work as follows:

- start an *asynchronous* Test
- after this test is done, start the next *asynchronous* Test
- do that for an arbitrary number of tests

Setting `QUnit.config.reorder` to `false` does not prevent the Tests from being started before the previous one is finished.

```
asyncTest('test1',function(){}); // all tests are started back on back
asyncTest('test2',function(){}); // but I would like to start them
asyncTest('test3',function(){}); // one after the other
```

I know that tests should be atomic, but in this case that would lead to one huge test, which itself may become error prone, so I would like to split it up.

Right now I am »packing« each Test into a wrapping function and call this function after one test is done, but that is somehow awkward and would like to know what kind of best practice exists for this.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't have an answer for this, but curious to see your implementation. The qunit source is open though, so maybe you could submit a patch.

Comment: Well, I ran in that problem because my Script introduced global, »private« variables, so each Test began to influence the result of the next. Chaining the tests would have made it possible to predict their values, but tests would not have been atomic any more. I found a solution to reset these globals, by reloading the entire script before each test and therefore I used the Qunit.testStart() method. So now I have both atomic tests and freshly initialised variables in each test.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution to reset these globals, by reloading the entire script before each test and therefore I used the Qunit.testStart() method. So now I have both atomic tests and freshly initialised variables in each test